# New try counter or new tries counter

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to say "a counter that counts new tries". Which is correct/more idiomatic: "a new try counter" or "a new tries counter"?

Comment: While I don't have a definitive answer (both sound as good as each other to me), I would be tempted to hyphenate the first two words in any case.  Otherwise it's likely to be read as a "try counter" that is new.  I feel that it might be hard to make this an unambiguous noun phrase in general, and perhaps your first, more descriptive version is better...

Comment: How about using [**attempts**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/attempt)? If this involves computer technology then [**tries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) can be ambiguous.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle Thanks for the comment. I'm little bit surprised that there is no strict rule that can be applied in this case, but at least now I know that both variants sound acceptable for native English speakers.

Comment: It’s not that they are both are equally acceptable; it’s that there are cases where idiomatic usage goes in opposite directions. E.g. *men’s room* (toilet) uses the plural *men* whereas *car yard* uses the singular *car*. Swapping singular for plural (or *vice versa*) doesn’t work in either case.

Comment: Is it a code variable being named? Is the word *counter* needed?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, In this case it's a name for a variable, and indeed `new_tries` or `attempts` may be a better choice:). But my goal is to figure out grammatical rules to be used in similar cases and improve my English.

Comment: There is no close relationship between Englich and source code. Good code skips the obvious, that's why *counter* is clutter, but in English, it helps. Self-documenting code was never quite that. I hate redundancy and found that in IT, it's desirable due to the protection it offers when things go wrong—it's even formally labeled redundancy. In code, jargon is good, brief is good, instant recognition is good. English? Not necessarily. Don't cross-contaminate.

Comment: What’s a new try?  Can there be old tries?  Once a new try has been counted does it become an old/previous try such that the counter should then be decremented?

Comment: @Jim Yes, there could be other try sessions. But the purpose of the question is to figure out the grammatical rules to be applied in such cases. Maybe I should ask a new, more generic question with `grammar` tag. Thanks.